# Calculate euclidean distance between groups in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have weekly data for various stores in the following form:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Store':['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3'], 'Week':[1, 2, 3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                           'Sales' : [20,30,40,21,31,41,22,32,42],'Cust_count' : [2,4,6,3,5,7,4,6,8]})

   Store Week Sales Cust_count
0   S1   1    20    2
1   S1   2    30    4
2   S1   3    40    6
3   S2   1    21    3
4   S2   2    31    5
5   S2   3    41    7
6   S3   1    22    4
7   S3   2    32    6
8   S3   3    42    8
```

As you can see the data is at a store week level and I want to calculate euclidean distance between each store for the same week and then take an average of the calculated distance. So for example the calculation for Store S1 and S2 would look as follows:

```
    For week 1: sqrt((20-21)^2 + (2-3)^2) = sqrt(2)
    For week 2: sqrt((30-31)^2 + (4-5)^2) = sqrt(2)
    For week 3: sqrt((40-41)^2 + (6-7)^2) = sqrt(2)
    The final value for distance between S1 and S2 = sqrt(2) which is calculated as 
average distance of the 3 weeks i.e. (3 * sqrt(2)) / 3
```

Finally the output should be as follows:

```
   S1    S2      S3
S1 0     1.414   2.818
S2 1.414 0       some val
S3 2.818 some val 0
```

I have some idea about group by function for grouping columns in data frame and scipy.spatial.distance.cdist for calculating euclidean distances, but I am unable to tie up these concepts and come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `pivot` then use `numpy` to do these calculations

```
df1  = (df.pivot(index='Store', columns='Week', values=['Sales', 'Cust_count'])
       #  .fillna(0)  # Uncomment if you want to treat missing store-weeks as 0s
       )
arr1 = df1['Sales'].to_numpy()
arr2 = df1['Cust_count'].to_numpy()

data = np.nanmean(np.sqrt(((arr1[None, :] - arr1[:, None])**2 
                         + (arr2[None, :] - arr2[:, None])**2)), 
                  axis=2)

pd.DataFrame(data, index=df1.index, columns = df1.index)
```

---

```
Store        S1        S2        S3
Store                              
S1     0.000000  1.414214  2.828427
S2     1.414214  0.000000  1.414214
S3     2.828427  1.414214  0.000000
```

Comment: This is smart :-)

Comment: It's a good solution. I do have a couple of observation, pivot function does not work for me, says "data must be 1-dimensional". I guess pivot_table function should work here. Secondly one potential drawback with pivot approach is that as I have data for 3 months and for 100 stores so basically after pivot there will be at least 1200 columns created which I feel may be computationally difficult to calculate the distances. Your thoughts?

Comment: There is one scenario where this solution is not working correctly i.e. when the number of weeks in both the stores are not same so for ex if i remove week 3 data from S2 store then also the above solution gives the same value(1.414) between S1 and S2 although in that case the value should be average of 1.414(week 1) , 1.414(week 2) and sqrt(40-0)^2 + (6-0)^2 for week 3

Comment: @bakas I wouldn't say it's working incorrectly. You just didn't specify what comparison to make for weeks that don't exist, and this is more cautious and only takes averages among weeks where data exist in both stores (I thought that was reasonable :D). Luckily the fix is *very* simple; tack on a `.fillna(0)` after the pivot and it works as you would like. You should now get `14.42530798568652` for S1 and S2 in the case you describe.

Comment: Maybe i put it too harshly, sorry for that. You are right I should have mentioned this scenario as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @bakas Ah I wasn't offended :D. It was a good and interesting question. Happy to help :D

Answer (score 2):

For loop with `permutations`

```
import itertools
s=list(itertools.permutations(df.Store.unique(), 2))
from scipy import spatial
l=[]
for x in s:
     l.append(np.sqrt(np.mean(np.sum((df[df.Store == x[0]].iloc[:, 2:].values - df[df.Store == x[1]].iloc[:, 2:].values)**2,axis=1),axis=0)))

s=pd.Series(l,index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s)).unstack()
s
Out[216]: 
          S1        S2        S3
S1       NaN  1.414214  2.828427
S2  1.414214       NaN  1.414214
S3  2.828427  1.414214       NaN
```

Comment: It works on the sample dataset but when I run on the full data set then I get an error in the l.append step saying "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (193,2) (97,2)". Is it due to the fact that two stores may not have same number of data points? If yes how do we resolve this

Answer (score 1):

you can first `merge` on Week to get all the combinations of stores, then calculate the column `dist` with the euclidean distance and finally [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with the `aggfunc='mean'`:

```
df.merge(df, on='Week', how='left', suffixes=('','_'))\
  .assign(dist = lambda x: np.sqrt((x.Sales - x.Sales_)**2 + (x.Cust_count - x.Cust_count_)**2))\
  .pivot_table(index='Store', columns='Store_', values='dist', aggfunc='mean')

Store_        S1        S2        S3
Store                               
S1      0.000000  1.414214  2.828427
S2      1.414214  0.000000  1.414214
S3      2.828427  1.414214  0.000000
```